# Position two elements next to eachother with float, clear:both alternative?

Tags: css, position, css-float

When i want to position two elements next to each other, like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"> ... </div>
    <div class="right"> ... </div>
</div>
```

i can use the following css:

```
.left, .right {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

but how do i make the wrapper adjust it's height to the child elements, without `clear:both` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `overflow` style. By not specifying any size for the parent, there isn't anything that actually overflows, but it will still make it contain its children:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Side note: Setting `display:inline` on an element that is set to float is pointless, as a floating element is alwas a block element:

```
.left, .right {
    float:left;
}
```

(Using `display:inline` on floating elements was however used to counter the double margin bug in IE6, so it can be found in older code.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i decided to go with your answers, it solved my doubt.

Answer (score 5):

Since a height isn't explicitly specified, setting `overflow:auto` will make the parent contain the child.

```
.wrapper {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cZtH/2/)

.......**BEFORE**                       ..................... **AFTER**

[image]

```
.left, .right {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
    margin:10px;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow:auto;
    background:red;
    width:140px;
    display:block;
}
```